# Problem with Ubuntu 12.04 boots after video drivers update

Tags: command-line, graphics, libreoffice, startup

After today's updates, my computer crashes (freezes) when I am using LibreOffice - I think something is wrong with the graphics. I have to constantly reboot my computer. I decided to update graphic card drivers, but the problem still exists. After multiple reboots, when computer is running, I see information about some 'avg recovery (...)' and next I see a black screen with command line log in. When I log in with my username and password, there is only information about the current Ubuntu version, new Ubuntu version and command line.
So, in conclusion I have two questions:

1. How can I run Ubuntu normally via this command line and remove this situation when system is running?
2. What is wrong with graphics in LibreOffice which causes the screen to freeze? (I have nvidia.)

----------EDIT-----------
I read that problem is probably with video drivers. I wil try to purge remove nvidia drivers and install those from x-swat PPA

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out from another thread.

```
After you've booted, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, and login using your credentials.

Remove all the nVidia drivers that you installed.

sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*

Install the drivers again:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

But I still have problem with video drivers - my computer sometimes freezes when I use LibreOffice. I unistall and install video drivers and LibreOffice and still nothing.